# Differential Operator on the manifold $G = SL(2, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-algebras, modular-forms

[image]

This computation was given in lecture yesterday. Here we let $f: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. We viewed $\mathcal{H}$ as the quotient space $G/K$ via $gK \mapsto g \cdot i$. We then defined $\widetilde{f}: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by : $ \widetilde{f} = \mu(g, i )^{2m} f(g \cdot i)$. Where g  = $\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d \: 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mu(g, z) = (cz + d)$.

Furthermore, we are considering the differential operator on the manifold $G = SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ via $$ X.f(g) := \frac{d}{dt} \: \big{|}_{t=0} f(g \text{exp  }(tX))$$ , Where $f$ is a differentiable function on $G$.

In this computation, $H$ is a basis element for the Lie($G$) such that $H =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \: 
\end{bmatrix}$.

In regards to the question I have; The first four lines of the computation are pretty straight forward, however, I am not immediately seeing the jump between the fourth and fifth lines, as well as the jump between the fifth and sixth lines. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f(g) =F(g.i)$ with $F(z)$ holomorphic on $\mathcal{H}$ then it should be $\frac{d}{dt} \: \big{|}_{t=0} f( \text{exp  }(tX)g)= \frac{d}{dt} \: \big{|}_{t=0} F(\exp(tX) .z)$ not $\frac{d}{dt} \: \big{|}_{t=0} f(g \text{ exp  }(tX))$ which depends on the modulo $K=SO_2$ representative we choose for $g$ in $z = g.i$. Or maybe they are using a weird right action notation $z= i.g$ ?

Comment: I believe it is a right action notation

Answer (score 1):

Both steps are applications of the product rule of differentiation. On the 4th line, let $\varphi(t):= e^{-2mt}$ and $\psi(t)$ the other terms. Then the 4th line reads $$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(\varphi(t)\psi(t))= \varphi(0)\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\psi(t) + \varphi'(0)\psi(0)$$ Now just plug in $\varphi(0)=1$, $\varphi'(0)=-2m$ and $\psi(0)$.

Te next line is doing the same trick again with $\mu$ and $f$.

Comment: Thank makes perfect scense, thank you!